# How to disable family sharing games?

Tags: steam

Is there a way to disable family shared games? I made a new account today but it still stays play instead of buy. I want to buy CS:GO personally.

Answer (score 1):

## There currently is no way to remove licenses granted through Family Sharing.

*Well, the loaner can revoke your licenses (access), but you can't remove them from the receiving end of them...*

However, since you're looking to buy the game, you could always go to the store page and purchase it from there.

As for making the buy button appear, you have one of three choices:

- Get the loaner to play one of his games, or:
- Get the loaner to revoke your access or deauthorize your machine.

Either way, the buy button will always lead you to the store page since payment confirmation happens there.